# What are 'service_args' for the selenium-python chrome webdriver?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I searched documentation for the argument `service_args` for the chrome webdriver, and I found the following pages: [here](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_chrome/selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.html#module-selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver) and [here](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver), which unfortunately do not contain any useful content to answer my question.

So where can I find proper documentation on the `service_args` argument?

Answer (score 3):

**`service_args`** are used inconjunction with **`chromedriver`** binary to pass the **`List of args to the chromedriver service`**

An example would be to pass the parameters e.g. *log file path*, *to ignore ssl errors*, *any ssl protocol* as follows :

```
service_args=["--log-path=D:\\Alex.log", "--ignore-ssl-errors=true", "--ssl-protocol=any"]
```

Your line of code will be :

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe', service_args=["--log-path=D:\\qc1.log", "--ignore-ssl-errors=true", "--ssl-protocol=any"])
```

Comment: But the question remains: Why is that not properly documented...?

Answer (score 2):

The reason why this is not documented is unknown.

But most likely this option can be used to pass arguments to the `chromedriver`. The list of options can be seen by running

```
chromedriver --help
```

For version 2.24 of `chromdriver` you get the following list:

```
Usage: chromedriver [OPTIONS]

Options
  --port=PORT                     port to listen on
  --adb-port=PORT                 adb server port
  --log-path=FILE                 write server log to file instead of stderr, increases log level to INFO
  --verbose                       log verbosely
  --version                       print the version number and exit
  --silent                        log nothing
  --url-base                      base URL path prefix for commands, e.g. wd/url
  --port-server                   address of server to contact for reserving a port
  --whitelisted-ips               comma-separated whitelist of remote IPv4 addresses which are allowed to connect to ChromeDriver
```

Comment: i tried with --silent but still shows some minor logs in command line. :(