# Chrome page opened with selenium remains blank

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, webdriver

I am trying to save a screenshot of a webpage, to do so I am trying to use Selenium. The problem is that once the webpage is opened, it stays blank with "data:" in the URL.

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options,executable_path='aPath/chromedriver.exe',service_log_path='aPath/mylog.txt')
driver.get('http://myURL.html')
screenshot=driver.save_screenshot('aPath/my_screenshot.png')
driver.quit()
```

NB: I have checked that my chromedriver version is compatible with my chrome browser version.

Comment: It remains that way utter `driver.get('http://myURL.html')`?

Comment: Hi @Guy, I am not sure to understand your comment, but I can say that I have tried with IE and it works fine, the problem is that I really need to make it work on Chrome

Comment: You are navigating to a page using `driver.get()`. After this command is it still showing blank page? or only before it?

Comment: When I use debug mode, it never get to the line `driver.get('http://myURL.html')`, it stay indefinitely at the line `driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options,e.....`

Comment: If it get stuck in the middle you should get an exception eventually, post it please.

Comment: It stays like 1 minute without any change then I get the following error: `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist`

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56637973/how-to-fix-selenium-devtoolsactiveport-file-doesnt-exist-exception-in-python

Comment: @Nefarious62 try removing all the options and only use `executable_path`.

Comment: Are you trying to load / parse an HTML document through Selenium? There might be a better extension for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for your help guys, actually Guy was right, I had to specify the port:

```
options.add_argument('--remote-debugging-port=9222')
```

Now it works!

Comment: Why the port is 9222? I mean based on which info you added this port? Or any other port can works?

Answer (score 2):

You need to update the *value* of the *Key* **`executable_path`** with the absolute path of the **chromedriver** binary and `service_args` as follows:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options,executable_path=r'C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe', service_args=["--log-path=C:\\path\\to\\mylog.log"])
```

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Selenium doesn't open the specified URL and shows data:,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52760842/selenium-doesnt-open-the-specified-url-and-shows-data/52761591#52761591)
- [What are 'service_args' for the selenium-python chrome webdriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47283378/what-are-service-args-for-the-selenium-python-chrome-webdriver/47283704#47283704)

Answer (score 0):

I found that adding the following option worked for me:

```
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
```

Details found in this answer:
[selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: unable to discover open pages using ChromeDriver through Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52208663/selenium-common-exceptions-webdriverexception-message-unknown-error-unable-to)